# Find the salary difference between two months

Tags: oracle

Suppose we have 3 columns in a table `emp_no, salary, month`

```
emp_no    salary    month
123       1000       jan
123       2000       feb
123       3000       march
```

So, output should look like:

```
emp_no    salary    month      diff
123       1000       jan       1000
123       2000       feb       1000
123       3000       march
```

Comment: What does the real data look like? Difficult to believe that the actual data for a month is "jan" ...

Comment: You need [analytics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652)

Comment: Eh, maybe analytics. A self-join would perform well if there are no missing months.

Comment: How do you keep years?

Answer (score 1):

```
select emp_no, 
       salary, 
       month,
       lag(salary) over (partition by emp_no order by month) - salary as diff_to_prev
       lead(salary) over (partition by emp_no order by month) - salary as diff_to_next
from emp_table;
```

This assumes that `month` is in fact a `DATE` (or timestamp) column that can be sorted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is not much info, this script aims to show the principle.

```
select t1.emp_no, t1.month as current month, t2.salary as current salary,
t2.month as prev_month, t2.salary as prev_salary,
coalesce(t2.salary - t1.prev_salary, 0) as difference

from SalaryTable t1
outter join (
select emp_no, month as prev_month, salary as prev_salary
from SalaryTable where month= 
    (select add_months(max(month),-1) from SalaryTable)
) t2 
on t1.emp_no = t2.emp_no
```

`COALESCE` may be changed to a `CASE` to handle mismatch between previuos and current months according to your needs.

Comment: `ISNULL` is not something that Oracle understands, as far as I know. Better to stick with standards like `COALESCE` or at least use Oracle's `NVL`

Comment: There is no need for the complicated self join.